# how can i limit the user input to two numeric characters?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program that asks the user for a day, month and year. However, the year entered has to have only two digits.
How can I limit the user to only two digits, and check for validity?

Right now, this is what I have: (Please no judgments, im a beginner)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int month;
int day;
int year;

int main() {
  //Ask user for a valid month and check validaty:
  cout << "Enter the month (1 to 12):\n";
  cin >> month;
  while (month < 1 || month > 12) {
    cout << "Invalid month, try again!\n"; 
    cin >> month; 
  }
  //Ask user for valid day and check validaty:
  cout << "Enter the day (1 to 31):\n";
  cin >> day; 
  while (day < 1 || day > 31) {
    cout << "Invalid day, try again!\n";
    cin >> day;
  }
  //Ask user for valid year and check validaty:
  cout << "Enter the year (YY):\n";
  cin >> year;
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless you use some platform specific code/library, you'll have to read the whole number first, then validate it.

Comment: Something like `while ((year < 0) || (year > 99)) {cout << "Invalid year, try again!\n"; cin >> year;}` would work okay, I think.

Comment: Even if you only read 2 characters of whatever the user input, there's no Standard IO way to prevent the user from typing in War and Peace. C++ IO is really, really dumb because it has to support the lowest common denominator of an extremely large umbrella of possible targets.